# is there contradiction in CSS causing border to remain shown?

Tags: html, css

I don't know if there is any contradiction in CSS which is causing the `.noborder` to not work:

```
 <table id="tableanswer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

...


<th width="30%" class="noborder"></th>
```

CSS:

```
#tableanswer td { 
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.noborder td{
    border:0px; 
}
```

UPDATE:

```
<table id="tableanswer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    ...


    <th width="30%" class="noborder"></th>
    <td width="30%" class="noborder"></td>
```

CSS:

```
    #tableanswer td { 
        border:1px black solid;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }


#tableanswer td.noborder {
    border:0px; 
}

#tableanswer th.noborder {
    border:0px; 
}
```

Comment: Accorting to your css, none of the headers will have borders. is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There are two problems.

1) you want "td.noborder" not ".noborder td"
2) the "#{id} td" is more powerful than a "td.{classname}"

So you need to strengthen your selector

```
#tableanswer td.noborder {
    border:0px; 
}
```

Here's the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/T9GVn/

**OLD**

Your code has a "TH" not a "TD".

Try:

```
.noborder th {
    border:0px; 
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried it in my app and it did not work strangely. I added you code and another code similar but change td to th but not working. I will include update of code

Comment: Could you fork the jsfiddle with your code or something like it?